# Can "if" be implemented using "call/cc"?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, control-flow, callcc, define-syntax

I've been told that "call/cc" can be used to implement arbitrary control flow constructs so I'm trying to implement all such constructs using "call/cc" but I'm having trouble. Assuming I didn't have "if" how would I implement it using "define-syntax" and "call/cc"? Is it possible or have I been misled? I know how to implement an unconditional jump using "call/cc" but at the machine level conditional execution is performed with branching instructions whose execution depends on the status bits of the processor. Without constructs of this type I don't see how it can be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't -- you have to have *some* way to test things and act on whether they're true or false.  You could get close though, with some functional representation of booleans.  For example, with a common church encoding:

```
(define (true x y) x)
(define (false x y) y)
```

and now you can consider a test (that returns one of these encoded booleans) as a function that accepts a "success" continuation and a "failure" one, and uses that to continue:

```
(define (if c x y) (c x y))
```

If you want to experiment with this, you need to consider the fact that Scheme is not a lazy language, so you need to thunk things up.  For example:

```
(define (true x y) (x))
(define (false x y) (y))
(define-syntax if
  [(if c x y) (c (lambda () x) (lambda () y))])
```

(But you still need to revise existing predicates etc to return these booleans.)

Either way, `call/cc` in itself isn't really doing anything relevant...

Comment: I didn't think that you could. Defining boolean values as functions changes the semantics of the language in such a way that boolean operators would have to be redefined because in Scheme any function is non-false when considered as a boolean value.

Comment: Yes, such a change would result in a different language...  That's why I started with "you can't".

Answer (score 3):

You can implement ***if*** with only higher-order procedures.  This is the obvious uncurried Church encoding:

```
IF ? T E === (? (lambda () T) (lambda () F))

TRUE     === (lambda (t _) (t))
FALSE    === (lambda (_ f) (f))
```

You don't need continuations at all.  True is a binary function that executes it's first argument; False is a binary function that executes it's second argument.  If is a ternary function that sequences them together by getting the True/False determined by the test (?), and giving it the two functions that delay the consequents.